# No abre sweet alert

Tags: ajax, sweetalert

previamente tengo este codigo que si funciona, 
quiero agregarle un mensaje de confirmacion del ingreso de los datos

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function AlertAgendado() {

      var form = $("#FormAgendado");
      var url = form.attr("action");
      var data = form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          data: data,
          success: function (result) {
              if (result.resultado) {
                  swal({
                      title: "¿Quiere Guardar?",
                      text: "¿Está seguro que quiere guardar?",
                      type: "info",
                      showCancelButton: true,
                      confirmButtonClass: "btn-info",
                      confirmButtonText: "Si, ¡Guardalo!",
                      closeOnConfirm: false
                  },
                  function () {
                      window.location.href = "/Home/TablaSSMN";
                  });

              } else {
                  swal("Error al Guardar!", result.resultado, "error");
              }
          }
      });
  };
 </script>
```

quedó así pero no hallo el problema, no abre al presionar "Guardar"

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function AlertAgendado() {

      var form = $("#FormAgendado");
      var url = form.attr("action");
      var data = form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          data: data,
          success: function (result) {
              if (result.resultado) {
                  swal({ 
                      title: "¿Quiere Guardar?",
                      text: "¿Está seguro que quiere guardar?",
                      type: "info",
                      showCancelButton: true,
                      confirmButtonClass: "btn-info",
                      confirmButtonText: "Si, ¡Guardalo!",
                      closeOnConfirm: false
                  },
                    function(){ 
                        swal("¡Hecho!",
                            "Acabas de Guardar.",
                            "success"),
                    window.location.href = "/Home/TablaSSMN"});
          }else {
                  swal("Error al Guardar!", result.resultado, "error");
              } 
      });  
  };      
</script>
```

Comment: si te fijas el alert de sweet lo tienes en le success

Comment: es decir luego de que registras tus datos mandas la alerta

Comment: deberias hacer antes de invocar a ajax

Comment: el ajax te retorna un objeto? puede que te este retornando un string

Comment: revisa esto: http://jsfiddle.net/yndmLgfb/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo logre separando la función del  `window.location.href="..."`

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function AlertAgendado() {

          var form = $("#FormAgendado");
          var url = form.attr("action");
          var data = form.serialize();
          $.ajax({
              url: url,
              type: "POST",
              data: data,
              success: function (result) {
                  if (result.resultado) {
                      swal({
                          title: "¿Seguro(a) que deseas Guardar?",
                          text: "¿Realmente que quieres guardar?",
                          type: "info",
                          showCancelButton: true,
                          cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
                          confirmButtonClass: "info",
                          confirmButtonText: "Si, ¡Guardalo!",
                          closeOnConfirm: false
                      },

                    function () {
                             swal({
                                title: "¡Hecho!",
                                text: "Los Datos se han guardado satisfactoriamente",
                                type: "success",
                                confirmButtonText: "Entendido",
                            },                 //AQUI <-------
                                function () {
                                    window.location.href = "/Home/TablaSSMN"
                                });
                            });

                  } else {
                      swal("Error al Guardar!", result.resultado, "error");
                  }
              }
          });
      };
  </script>
```

Gracias por su ayuda :D